# Combine CSV files to one file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a lot of files with following sample content

File1

```
ENGLISH|0|1|0|0|3|0|1483|1|0|183
TURKISH|1|0|0|0|1|60649|0|0|0|649
AZERBAIJANI|0|0|2|0|2|0|0|45|0|45
URDU|0|10|0|1|1|0|0|0|1409|109
```

File2

```
HINDI|0|2|0|0|2|0|1183|0|0|1183
TURKISH|1|0|0|0|1|60649|0|0|0|60649
AZERBAIJANI|0|0|2|0|2|0|0|45|0|45
URDU|0|0|0|1|1|0|0|0|1409|1409
```

FileN

```
DANISH|0|2|0|0|2|0|1183|0|0|1183
ENGLISH|1|0|0|0|1|60649|0|0|0|60649
AZERBAIJANI|0|0|2|0|2|0|0|45|0|45
URDU|0|0|0|1|1|0|0|0|1409|1409
```

I have to sort all these files and then add each column to same column number of all files and finally have a single file bases on language name. Language name can be considered as KEY. So all records with same KEY in all files should be added. How I can do it ?

I am using linux as OS. Is there any other utility that can do the same job ?

Comment: Have you tried to code anything in Python already? If not, and you're just looking to solve the problem somehow, I think it's better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or ServerFault (note that cross-posting between sites is discouraged).

Comment: you can see `pandas` which might help

Comment: You can use a `dict` to read the files as: `key:language`, `value:numpy-array` and proceed with your work.

Comment: How about a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?  Or at least expected output?

Comment: you should be able to do it with not much difficulty using a shell script as well, but that might be better suited for SuperUser as @yeputons already suggested

Comment: Could you edit the question to show what the output would be for your example.